# error: expected expression before ‘void’

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Im using Cloud 9 environment and this code is bugging me, we got it for an assignment it shows the following compilation errors, i am stuck with these

> lab.c: In function ‘main’: lab.c:14:12: error: expected expression
>   before ‘void’
>       getType(void);
>
> ^ lab.c:14:12: error: too many arguments to function ‘getType’
>   lab.c:4:7: note: declared here  float getType(void);
>
> ^ lab.c: In function ‘getType’: lab.c:20:5: warning: format ‘%f’
>   expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘float
>   (*)(int,  int)’ [-Wformat=]
>        printf("Total airfare is: %.2f",ticketPrice);

```
    //calculation cost aircost by given type

#include <stdio.h>
float getType(void);
float ticketPrice(int type,int noOfSeats);
int main(void)
{
   int type,noOfSeats;

   printf("Enter the type(1 or2): ");
   scanf("%d", &type);
   printf("Enter the no of seats: ");
   scanf("%d", &noOfSeats);
   getType(void);
   ticketPrice(type,noOfSeats);
   return 0;
}
float getType(void)
{
    printf("Total airfare is: %.2f",ticketPrice);

}
float ticketPrice(int type,int noOfSeats)
{
   float Tprice;

   if (type=1){
      printf("Economy Class\n");
      type=90000;
      printf("90,000\n");
      Tprice=90000*noOfSeats;
      printf("Total airfare is:%.2f ",Tprice);
      return 0;
   }
   else if(type=2){
      printf("Business class\n");
      type=120000;
      printf("120,000\n");
      Tprice=120000*noOfSeats;
      printf("Total airfare is :%.2f ",Tprice);
   }
   else if(type!=1||2){
       printf("invalid type");
      return 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: You can't pass `void`  as a parameter. Just leave it blank. So it will be `getType();`

Comment: Not your problem here, but `ticketPrice` is a function, not a usable value. I'd expect running `getType` to either fail or print weird results. You need to call the function.

Comment: `getType(void);` ==> `somevar = getType();` But the function does not return a value. Please enable compiler warnings.

Comment: Remove `float getType(void)
{
    printf("Total airfare is: %.2f",ticketPrice);

}` , `float getType(void);` and `getType(void);`

Comment: `type=1` --> `type==1`,  `type!=1||2` --> `type!=1 && type!=2`

Comment: `type=2` --> `type==2`, and should `return 0;` at last of this block.

Comment: Wow thanks a million guys :D  it compiled and it works :D Cheers :D  i'm not much familiar with the void functions and functions much still, So thanks once again for explaining and helping me to get through :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define a function that takes no arguments in C, the arguments should explicitly be `void`. You've done that. The error is when you call the function:

```
getType(void);
```

Here, you must omit the `void`:

```
getType();
```

But your function returns a `float` and you'll probably want to store the result. And your function should actually reurnt a float. At the moment, it doesn't return anything, which leads to undfined behaviour.

Compile you code again and switch warnings on. You have many other errors in your code. For example, `if (type = 1)` will *set* `type` to 1 and then enter the code block. You want to *check* the value, for which you should use `==`.

Comment: Oh.I understood , i fixed the if (type = 1) to (type==1) now it got compiled and works, Thanks for explaining :D